# Undefined array key "productqty" Laravel 8

Tags: mysql, laravel-8

I am developing eCommerce using laravel-8. I trying to updated current stock after checkout. I am getting this error "Undefined array key productqty". where is my script problem i can't read it. **$request->get('prorder')** this is order id. same order id insert multiple time in **orderDetails** table. I want to update current stock in product table.

```
  $order = $request->get('prorder');

    $datas = DB::table('orderDetails') 
     ->select(array('order_id','ProductId','productqty'))
     ->where('order_id', '=', $order)  
     ->get();
    
   $pquenty=array_filter($datas['productqty']);
   $value=array_values($pquenty);
 
  for ($i=0; $i<count ($value); $i++) {    

   $qupdate = DB::update('UPDATE Product set totalstock=(totalstock - $value[$i]) WHERE id = "'.$datas['ProductId'][$i].'" ');
   }
```

Comment: get() returns collection object. maybe you try get()->toArray().

Comment: get()->toArray() this is not working

Answer (score 0):

Your $order = $request->get('prorder'); is using get method. Most likely is in array.

```
  $datas = DB::table('orderDetails') 
     ->select(array('order_id','ProductId','productqty'))
     ->where('order_id', '=', $order[0])  
     ->get();
```

Try change the code from the above updated code. Hope this resolve your issue.

Comment: $order = $request->get('prorder');

        $datas = DB::table('orderDetails') 
         ->select(array('order_id','ProductId','productqty'))
         ->where('order_id', '=', $order)  
         ->first();

Comment: If that the case, for loop may not sure required.

Answer (score 0):

```
$order = $request->get('prorder');
```

This is the right script. above is wrong.

```
$order = $request->get('prorder');

$datas = DB::table('orderDetails') 
 ->select(array('order_id','ProductId','productqty'))
 ->where('order_id', '=', $order)  
 ->get();


foreach ($datas as $datas) {
    $pquna = $datas->productqty;
    $pid= $datas->ProductId;
      
    $qupdate = DB::update('UPDATE Product set totalstock=(totalstock - "'.$pquna.'") WHERE id = "'.$pid.'" ');
}
```